# Make movie in MatLab

Tags: matlab, animation, geometry

I am trying to create a short animation in MatLab using the `movie` command.  The animation is supposed to draw a circle.  However, when I run the following script, the 'o' sign just jumps randomly around the figure window without leaving a trace behind.

```
z = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
nframes = length(z);
Frames = moviein(nframes);
for i = 1:nframes
    x = cos(i);
    y = sin(i);
    plot(x,y,'o','erase','none');
    Frames(:,i) = getframe;
    pause(0.25);
end
movie(Frames,1)
```

If anyone can explain to me why the script is not working correctly, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What does the 'erase' argument do in the call to `plot`?

Comment: I thought perhaps I should include it so that the 'o' sign does not disappear when the loop starts over.  But I suppose it is redundant?

Comment: I would say try it and see what behavior you get.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the movie does actually plot the points it is supposed to, and the animation shows the 'o' jumping from one point to the next in a correct manner.  The problem is that the points do not "stick", so that when the animation is complete, the figure window is left blank.

Comment: That's what made me suspect the 'erase' and 'none' from that one function call. What's happening is that it's drawing the entire frame (without transparency) instead of just drawing the 'o'. I'm not sure why though. I wish I knew Matlab better so I could help you...

Comment: Appreciate your comments though.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kristian: These might be of interest to you: [Matlab Simulation: Point (symbol) Moving from start point to end point and back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2796109/97160), [Matlab for loop animations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7464653/97160)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This draws a circle. Hope it helps.

```
z = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
nframes = length(z);
Frames = moviein(nframes);
for i = 1:nframes
    x = cos(2*pi*i/nframes);
    y = sin(2*pi*i/nframes);
    plot(x,y,'o');
    hold on
    Frames(:,i) = getframe;
    pause(0.01);
end
movie(Frames,1)
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks a lot.  I should have remembered to include "hold on", I see.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to loop through the `z` vector. Try changing `x = cos(i)` to `x = cos(z(i))` and same with `y = sin(i)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  However, I still get the same problem.

Comment: If you want the points to stick to the plot, try the `hold on;` command after you call `plot`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just received the same information above :).  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late with this but i'm hoping it may be helpful to someone out there...
I'm looking into ways to animate points on a circle and, although i haven't figured it out yet, i've noticed something in the suggested code above that might make your circle look more 'circular'.
after you set

```
hold on
```

if you add another line to just say

```
axis('equal');
```

you will get axis which scale with the plot and so your circle is not corrupted depending on the figure window dimensions.